# transcription how-to

Tags: discussion, support, closure, canonical-q-a

I just learned that questions about transcribing music are off topic.

I do agree that if someone has a tune that they're having trouble notating, they shouldn't be able to just come here out of laziness and let us transcribe the difficult phrase for them.  However, I think it is reasonable for us to help people learn how to transcribe.

Here is a proposal: how about we select or create a canonical answer addressing *how to transcribe*, and then all transcription questions could be closed, thanks to the canonical Q-A?

Comment: We kind of already did that, but the quality of the accepted answer was not that good since the OP really just wanted the sheet music.

Comment: @Dom - is there a canonical answer?  Does this site have a list of canonical answers?  Are you saying a how-to answer was written some time ago?  If so, can you help me find it?

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/how-do-i-write-music-down-from-a-recording < this is the one I was thinking about

Comment: The top voted answer to that question seems to be the one we want: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/27235/45266

Comment: @user45266 - Maybe I should remove my answer about getting started with transcription and shift it over to that question, and then all transcription questions could point to that one.

Comment: @Dom - pinging you too, let me know what you think.